# Multiple ViewModels in MainWindowViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I will probably have a stupid and many times explained question, but I did not find a simple googling answer to my question.
(I'm just a beginner in C# so don't judge strictly, OOP is still a bit difficult for me to understand).
I have a WPF MVVM application, inside of which I would like to implement several ViewModel for which there is one View.
I want to be able to change SelectedViewModel to SelectedViewModel_One and SelectedViewModel_Two, where the same methods will be implemented inside. (as in the example).

```
 public  class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
        private bool _Disposed;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null){}
        protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null){}
        public void Dispose(){}
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool Disposing){}

    }


public partial class SelectedViewModel_One : ViewModel
    {
        public void Move(){}
    }

public partial class SelectedViewModel_Two : ViewModel
    {
        public void Move(){}
    }


     internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
     {
        private ViewModelAbstractBaseOrSmthLikeThat selectedViewModel = null;
        public ViewModelAbstractBaseOrSmthLikeThat SelectedViewModel
        {
             get { return selectedViewModel; }
             set { Set(ref selectedViewModel, value); }
        }
     }

     --------------
     --XAML
     --------------
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SampleApplication.ViewModels"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel></vm:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding SelectedViewModel}">
          <!--Components and binding to SelectedViewModel -->
    </Grid>
```

But how to properly organize the architecture of the application? What do I need to add, or change in the code of MainWindowViewModel instead of "ViewModelAbstractBaseOrSmthLikeThat"

I need to work with interfaces, and implement a base class?
Or please give me a link to the simplest example how to do this, so that by changing in MainWindowViewModel - SelectedViewModel - I can call Move() methods from SelectedViewModel_One and SelectedViewModel_Two.

---

I have several devices which are controlled via RS232 commands.
All the devices have the same functions but the commands are different.
That's why there is a single View for the program

Comment: `SelectedViewModel_One` and `SelectedViewModel_Two` could both inherit from a base class or they could both implement an interface, both approaches will work.

Comment: You should define Move() as a member of a common interface or as an abstract member of a common abstract base class. Now if your goal is to expose one particular view model class you define the SelectedViewModel property of type interface or abstract base class.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville Could you provide a very brief example in the answers?

Comment: You could alternatively use composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: @Andy Could you also  provide a very brief example in the answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to proceed with a base class:

```
public abstract class RS232DeviceViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public abstract void Move();
}

public class FirstDeviceViewModel : RS232DeviceViewModel
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SecondDeviceViewModel : RS232DeviceViewModel
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your `MainWindowViewModel`, you would declare `SelectedViewModel` as an `RS232DeviceViewModel`:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private RS232DeviceViewModel selectedViewModel

    public RS232DeviceViewModel SelectedViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedViewModel != value)
            {
                selectedViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fields and properties are automatically initialized with the default value of the type. You don't have to do this explicitly.

Comment: @BionicCode. yes, I was simply matching the original declaration in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

An approach based on composition would have the functionality in a class both viewmodels would contain. Seeing as these are viewmodels, the class might itself be a viewmodel but it could just be instantiated as a private member of the viewmodels and it's functionality exposed as a method, func or the like.
The latter would often be called a service.
You might have a MoveCalculationService class or a SinalInterpretationService class... for example.

```
 public class FooViewModel : ObservableObject
 {
     public Bar SomeObject {get;set;}
     public Signal SomeSignal(param ....)
     {
     }
 }
```

That can be used in both viewmodels

```
 public class SelectedViewModel_One  
 {
     public FirstDeviceViewModel (FooViewModel someMovingThing )
     {
        SomeMovingThing = someMovingThing;
     }

     // Maybe bind to SomeMovingThing.SomeProperty.
     public FooViewModel SomeMovingThing {get;set;}

     public void Move()
     {
         // Maybe reference instance of FooViewModel ;
     }
  }
```

You can bind to SomeMovingThing.SomePropertyInThat. You could reference it in methods in FirstDeviceViewModel.  You could pass in unique parameters or functions from SelectedViewModel_One and SelectedViewModel_Two.

Composition is useful in isolating functionality in a re useable and dependency injection friendly manner.

Composition is quite a common approach.

In teams that use SOLID you're usually expected to have viewmodels which contain no specific logic. Any commands or functionality is usually obtained from a DI container and that means separate classes.

You might want to share the same data across more than one viewmodel. For this sort of thing you can inject your service/viewmodel using dependency injection and use the scope of that to control when you get a new instance or an existing one.

Even if you're just writing unit tests, it's simpler if you have all your logic split into small chunks and easily isolated.

Some apps, you might want a mix of both. It's very common to have a base viewmodel has properties such as IsBusy and IsDirty for example.